# Result not match for text area (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question which concerns `jquery.urlive` plugin. This plugin is used to graph content from other website and generate to HTML element, so I use it to 
develop my personal project. I have a problem which I don't know how to solve, should I customize the library or are there solutions?

I would like to duplicate text area more than 2 (let's say I have done with duplication), but they are the same functions, which means when there is url in the text area one and then the result will appear for result one and others are the same.

Obviously my problem when there was url on text are one, all the results for other text are also shown.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/samphors/4KftC/77/

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the urllive only for the changed element

```
$('.demo').on('input propertychange', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $ct = $this.next();
    $this.urlive({
        container: $ct,
        callbacks: {
            onStart: function () {
                $ct.html('<span class="loading">Loading...</span>');
            },
            onSuccess: function (data) {},
            noData: function () {
                console.log('y')
                $ct.html('');
            }
        }
    });
}).trigger('input');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vn2kqopc/)

Answer (score 0):

`if(f.match(urlPattern) && d == true){
        var o = f.match(urlPattern), link = o[0];
    $(".frame").attr("src",link);
        d = false;
    }`

try this
http://jsfiddle.net/4KftC/79/